# Limits under intersection

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am not sure because that element sign under the intersection sign is not aligned. Every time I use `\bigcap`, `\limits`, for instance,

`$$N(G) = \bigcap \limits_{H\in \Sigma} N_G(H)$$`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not aligned" (see [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUIJk.png))? That's its natural position, slightly below vertical. [Here's a view of `$H \in \Sigma$` only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2wK8.png). The vertical "misalignment" is exaggerated within the subscript, that's all.

Comment: ...also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 3):

You can judge by yourself which one to prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\raisedin}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{\depth}{$\in$}}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Normal
\[
a\in X = \bigcap_{H\in \Sigma} N_G(H)
\]
Raised
\[
a\raisedin X = \bigcap_{H\raisedin \Sigma} N_G(H)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this, but....

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\raisedin}[1][]{\raisebox{0.05em}{#1$\in$}}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 N(G) = \bigcap \limits_{H\raisedin[\scriptsize] \Sigma} N_G(H)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```